# c# - button click not executing method while using SignalR

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I have a web forms application that uses signalR. I want to execute a method on the click of a button but when I click the button nothing happens. My hub class is defined as follows:[image]

I also use the method "generateStatistics" in the hub class:
[image]

Now my client code is supposed to run the generateStatistics method on the click of a button. Here is the button code:

[image]

And finally this is what my client code looks like:
[image]

So, when I click the button nothing happens or at least the method isn't running because my breakpoint is never hit in the generateStatistics method. I did a bit of client javascript debugging in IE and it seems as though the connection is being made properly but the button click handler just doesn't seem to do anything. I guessed that it might be because the button is an asp server control with the runat specified but I turned it to an input html control and it still didn't seem to work or run the method. If you are wondering what the purpose of me using signalr here is that in the generateStatistics method I update the client with progress messages which you can infer from the javascript created method addProgress.

Comment: It is better to add the text of your code into the question that screen shots. Text we can coppy and paste the code, screen shots we can not. Paste your code into the question and click the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Add some intrusive debuggin and see what your result is. `conn.start()
    .done(function(){ alert("Connected");$("#btnStart").click(function(){alert("btn clicked")}); })
    .fail(function(){ alert("Something broke!"); });`

Answer (score 0):

When you use ASP.NET, the HTML element ID will be different than what you specify on the control.

Try to use this instead:

```
$('#<%= btnStart.ClientID %>').click(function () { ... });
```